# Mapping BigInteger in YAML file with PlayFramework

Tags: jpa, playframework, yaml

given the following model example:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="tierenforcers")
public class TierEnforcer extends Model {
    public BigInteger maxStorage; // expressed in B
}
```

How can I map a BigInteger in my yml file?  If I do something like:

```
TierEnforcer(joeTE):
    maxStorage:             5368709120
```

I don't get an error on #play test startup, but a NULL value in my database (BigInteger created as decimal(19,2) in MySQL, but persisting values into this seems to be working fine with JPA otherwise)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Play! uses [snakeyml](http://code.google.com/p/snakeyaml/) under the hood. Look at their website for more info.

Looking at [this yaml example](http://code.google.com/p/snakeyaml/source/browse/src/test/resources/constructor/test-primitives1.yaml) you can try to create a BigInteger and then assign it to your instance

```
bigInteger(myBigInt): 123456789012345678901234567890123456789

TierEnforcer(joeTE):
    maxStorage:             myBigInt
```

Hope it works ;)

Comment: Thanks for pointing me towards the right syntax. I just tried this and got something different: `Execution exception RuntimeException occured : Cannot load fixture data.yml: java.math.BigInteger cannot be cast to java.util.Map`

Comment: Accepting this answer, since it pointed me towards realizing that it can't be done.  Switched to long....thanks!