# Custom DataType loading from YML using fixture

Tags: playframework

MyInt.java

```
public class MyInt() implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1L;
    private int myInt;

    public MyInt(Integer i) {
        this.myInt = i;
    }
}
```

TestModel.java

```
public class TestModel extends Model {
    public MyInt myInt; 
}
```

How can I populate that from YML. I tried with -

```
MyInt(test):
    myInt:  5
```

But, it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Play is using [snakeyml](http://code.google.com/p/snakeyaml/). Check [this](http://code.google.com/p/snakeyaml/wiki/Documentation#JavaBeans) for custom java beans

This answer might also help: [Mapping BigInteger in YAML file with PlayFramework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8430878/mapping-biginteger-in-yaml-file-with-playframework/8431362#8431362)